# Add a second wifi router to connect to incase the main one is offline in Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi 4, and would like to add a second wifi access point, as I want to carry it with me to other places with different ssids and passwords. I will provide the current network-config.

```
version: 2
wifis:
  renderer: networkd
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "ssid here":
        password: "longer password"
```

I did of course censor out the ssid and password. I would like to add a second one that I can connect to if the first on is inaccessible. How can I do this while editing files only from something like a chromebook.

Answer (score 2):

You simply edit your network config file and insert a new block for each additional access point:

```
version: 2
wifis:
  renderer: networkd
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "ssid here":
        password: "longer password"
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "new SSID":
        password: "new password"
```

Then run:

```
sudo netplan apply
```